# Using args facility

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace WS_7_A
{
    class Calculator
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~ Acme Calculator-o-Matic ~~~~~~");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter two integers to add...");
            double number1 = Convert.ToDouble(args[0]);
            double number2 = Convert.ToDouble(args[1]);
            Console.WriteLine("Answer: {0}", Calculator.add(number1, number2));
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }


        private static int add(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a + b);
        }

        private static double add ( double a , double b)
        {
            return ( a + b);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I receive is `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `args` represents command-line arguments that are passed when you first start your program through the Windows command prompt. It doesn't read user input during runtime. For reading user input while your program is running, you need to use `Console.ReadLine()` and friends.

Comment: What command line parameters are you using? Also, it's always a good idea to check the length of `args`.

Answer (score 3):

The `args` array parameter that is passed to the `Main` method will contain the command line parameters that are passed to your executable. If none are passed it will be empty.

Your code expects 2 parameters to be passed at the command line when running the executable: `args[0]` and `args[1]` since this is what you are trying to read. So to properly run your application you must pass those 2 parameters at the command line:

```
Calculator.exe 1 2
```

Or maybe you want to read them from the user in which case you don't use the `args` variable but you read them from the console:

```
double number1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
double number2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Now you can simply run your application using `Calculator.exe`.

Comment: It will not let me enter a path

Comment: Or deal with the case where the program is started with no arguments. Check `Args.Length`.

Comment: @Evildommer5, no you should not ignore the error. You should fix your code. Depending on what you are trying to do you should either pass those 2 parameters when running your application at the command line or you should ask the user to enter them in which case you should use Console.ReadLine as shown in my answer instead of trying to access the `args`  variable.

Comment: Im just simply compliing the code, so where do i declare that they are, i dont have a build .exe

Comment: @Evildommer5, if you want to use command line arguments you could go to the properties of the project in Visual Studio and in the Debug tab there is a `Command line arguments` area where you can hardcode some arguments tat you want to be automatically passed when you run the application inside VS. If you want to have the user enter those values in the console you should use Console.ReadLine as shown in my answer instead of args[0] and args[1].

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the count of your args array? And do you start the program with your console like this?

```
myprogram.exe 34 54
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to build this .exe and then run it from the command line using two arguments (e.g. `app.exe 1 2`).

You can also do this from within VS by going to the project properties (right click the project -> properties), under debug and adding the command line arguments into the box (e.g. `1 2`).

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
double number1 = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Or even:

```
double number1;
if (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number is Invalid");
    //Some sort of code to allow the user to re-enter the number, or exit the app as preferred.
}
```

The `args` is what is passed into the command line arguments.
For example calling:

`MyApp.exe 123 456`

- `args[0]` will be 123
- `args[1]` will be 456